# Prevent row selection in datagrid when clicking on a checkbox cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox, selection

I have a DataGridView where each row has a checkbox in it.  I only want the selected row to change when the user clicks on one of the text cells.  However, if a checkbox is clicked I would still like to have the checkbox change its state and catch this event.

I have searched everywhere and found a couple of solutions that fix half of the problem, but I haven't found anything that 100% prevents the selected row from changing when I click on my checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a work around.

Instead of listening for SelectionChanged events, I listened for CellMouseClick events and then toggled my *own* flag for which row is selected.

I also changed the default row style so that there is no indication of which row is selected.  Then i added some code to change the row style of whichever row was selected according to *my own* row.

---

Below is the code *just* for listening to CellMouseClicks on certain columns, the rest is very specific to my application.

```
    void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure it is a left click
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Make sure it is on a cell
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                // Only allow certain columns to trigger selection changes (1 & 2)
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2)
                {
                    // Set my own private selected row index
                    setSelectedRow(e.RowIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Actions for other columns...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```